# Семантическое подобие предложений на разных языках

Tags: алгоритм, семантика

Как из ряда предложений на Русском языке найти наиболее близкое по смыслу на английское предложение?
  Делал скрипт который с помощью API Яндекс переводит предложение, потом приводит все его слова в начальную форму с помощью phpMorphy, и сверяет с начальной формой слов в русских предложениях, где больше совпадений, то и более похожее... Качество нахождение соответствий не высоко, как и скорость работы. Находить нужно из 100к+ предложений.
  Есть мнение, что нахождение произведения семантических расстояний между каждым словом английского предложения и набора русских должно дать лучший результат.
  Подскажите где можно получать данные о семантическом расстоянии между словами?
  Есть ли возможность находить семантическое расстояние между словами на разных языках?
  Возможно есть готовые решения для моих целей?

Comment: Ради интереса, какое приложение у этого? синхронизация текстов?

Comment: @Fat-Zer Широкое приложение в SEO. Подбор ключевых слов, работа со сниппетами...